# Javascript code to record click on hyperlink - Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, record, qualtrics

For a survey experiment built in Qualtrics, I need to record whether respondents clicked on a hyperlink to an external webpage. I am not proficient with Javasctript. What would be the simplest solution to record this information? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this, one of the more common methods is actually a "click-thru" page that acts as a intermediary page between your site and the external one.

If you want "only javascript", you'll have to make a callback (such as via ajax) to another page when the links are being clicked.

For instance, you would setup a link like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="return externalLink(this.href);">click me</a>
```

Then, you would have a javascript function like the following:

```
function externalLink(location) {
    // make an ajax GET request to your "logging" page
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/log.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location));
    req.send(null);

    // return "true" to allow the link to be followed
    return true;
}
```

The issue with this method is that ajax requests can take a while due to unforeseen network issues, server processing time, etc. In the end, it may miss a few clicks here and there and may not be the best approach if you want "perfect" results.

I'd recommend trying a click-thru page for all external URLs, that way you'd be certain to capture all clicks. This could be done via something like the following all (in PHP):

Main HTML page full of links:

```
<a href="/clickthru.php?url=<?php echo urlencode("http://www.example.com"); ?>">click me</a>
```

The clickthru.php page:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];
if (!empty($url)) {
    // perform all of your logging that's necessary
    // ...

    // redirect this page to the desired external URL
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302);
    exit();
}
```